# Foreign Fighter Classification \ Jurisdiction

Tags: criminal-law, international, laws-of-war, terrorism

Two [British nationals](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/isis-beatles-transferred-syrian-prison-us-military-custody/story?id=66172473&cid=clicksource_4380645_null_headlines_hed) are alleged to have executed Americans under the guise of ISIL and are in American military custody. Assume that the suspects remain in American custody and are not transferred to Britain or any other body.

- What are the subjects labeled as?  Enemy soldier combatants?   Common criminal?
- What US venues would have jurisdiction to try the Britons?  SDNY?

Comment: As a bit of context, there would be a good argument that they could have been tried as enemy combatants before a military tribunal. But, experience post-9-11 has shown that regular courts not bewitched by an absence of procedural case law as military tribunals are, actually tend to secure convictions that are more swift and more secure than the Article I military tribunal approach did, and that they are not more likely to produce acquittals - so none of the justifications for military tribunal approaches proved to be empirically correct.

Answer (score 1):

**What are the subjects labeled as? Enemy soldier combatants? Common criminal?**

The wording of the charges, taken from the Department of Justice's [press release](https://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/isis-militants-charged-deaths-americans-syria), suggests they are both common criminals and terrorists (allegedly):

> Kotey and Elsheikh are each charged with:
>
> - conspiracy to commit hostage taking resulting in death
> - four counts of hostage taking resulting in death
> - conspiracy to murder United States citizens outside of the United States
> - conspiracy to provide material support to terrorists — hostage taking and murder — resulting in death
> - conspiracy to provide material support to a designated foreign terrorist organization resulting in death
>
> <sub>re-formatted</sub>

**What US venues would have jurisdiction to try the Britons? SDNY?**

Their first appearance was in the Federal Court at Alexandria, Virginia in October 2020, and I cannot find anything to suggest any change of venue applications have been made - but it's early days relatively speaking. (Also, they're no longer British citizens.)

**UPDATE**

The [Eastern District of Virginia Indictmement](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.justice.gov/opa/press-release/file/1325721/download&ved=2ahUKEwj1stq9mPrxAhWHY8AKHUXSALEQFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw1CIwBBncRTqFaasSl7eyZ0) refers to Kotey and Elsheikh as both [**Specially Designated Global Terrorists**](https://www.state.gov/executive-order-13224/) and [**Foreign Terrorist Organisation**](https://www.state.gov/foreign-terrorist-organizations/) **(FTO) fighters.**

Comment: Is there any information available to suggest why the Eastern District of Virginia has jurisdiction?  Normally a complaint would cover this explicitly, I believe.

Comment: @phoog Nope, I can't find the actual indictment - everything I can find stems from the October 2020 FBI press releases. Maybe they landed at Langley AFB and Alexandria was the nearest Fed court?